# Apache on OSX refuses to allow access to a properly aliased directory

Tags: macos, apache

Despite the fact that I explicitly allow any permissions, Apache refuses to give public access to my folder

```
Alias /projects "/Users/username/projects"

<Directory "/Users/username/projects">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

On Windows, this configuration (with the proper path, of course) works just fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: So what error are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check file permissions as well.  Open terminal:

1. CD to that directory.
2. Find out what the userid of the apache process is (typically _www on OS X).  You can further verify this by sudo more /etc/passwd.
3. Find the permissions of that directory.  You want _www (Apache user) or world to be able to read at least.  ls -la |more will give you ownership and permissions look for projects.
4. Change either the ownership (chown) or the permissions (chmod +rx) on the directory.  I'm not going to give you the command, because if it's wrong, you could really screw up that directory.

If this stuff is foreign to you, try man chown and man chmod from commandline.